# What is an example of a weakly consistent but not strongly consistent estimator?

Tags: estimators, consistency

I just can't think of any example.

I am using definitions: weakly consistent: $\forall \varepsilon > 0 \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} P(|\hat{\theta}_n - \theta| \geq \varepsilon) = 0$; strongly consistent: $P(\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \hat{\theta}_n = \theta) = 1$.

Answer (score 5):

EDIT: I originally read this question the wrong way: not weakly consistent but strongly consistent!

All strongly consistent estimators are also weakly consistent because almost sure convergence implies convergence in probability.

In the definition of *strong* consistency, $P(\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \hat{\theta}_n = \theta) = 1$ means that the sequence $\hat{\theta}_n$ converges *almost surely* to the constant $\theta$.

In the definition of *weak* consistency, $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} P(|\hat{\theta}_n - \theta| \geq \varepsilon) = 0$ means that the sequence $\hat{\theta}_n$ converges *in probability* to the constant $\theta$.

Read [more about modes of convergence on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convergence_of_random_variables). There you can find examples for different types of convergence.

Examples for convergence in distribution or probability typically involve sequences of independent random variables. Almost sure convergence is a property that concerns the joint distribution of the whole sequence. A strongly consistent sequence  $\hat\theta_1,\hat\theta_2,\dots$ of estimators for $\theta$ is typically not independent, although it is possible to construct  sequences of independent random variables that almost surely converge to a constant. An easy such example are uniform random variables with shrinking support.

Comment: Thanks for taking a look at my old question. I think you misunderstood – I was asking the other way around. I wanted an example of an estimator that is convergent in probability, but is not an convergent "almost surely". Luckily on the Wikipedia page you linked there is [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proofs_of_convergence_of_random_variables#propA1i) which might suggest an answer

Comment: Ah, you are right! Sorry, and thanks for having a look! I came to your question because I also was looking for a nice example of weak but not strong consistency :-)
Did you meanwhile find a *simple* example of a real *estimator* that is only weakly consistent?

Comment: @Ute: If you by *real* means some estimator in practical use I guess you are out of luck. But it is not that difficult to construct artificial examples (but I am out of time).

Comment: @kjetilbhalvorsen, yes, artificial examples can be constructed. I was wondering if it is worth a bounty for a real or at least convincingly realistic example (easy to find estimators with infinite variance, for example), but I am quite pessimistic.